# iOS JSON Response twice, JSON Null

Tags: php, ios, json, nsdata

Stuck on why my json response is repeated twice in some cases (can't isolate) thus causing my jsonData to be (null).  I use the same php for Android, but only my iOS seen this issue.  Here is my objective-C code which produces a response twice - sometimes:

```
NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData length]];

        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

        [request setURL:url];
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];

        NSError *error = [[NSError alloc] init];
        NSHTTPURLResponse *response = nil;
        NSData *urlData=[NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];

        NSLog(@"Response code: %d", [response statusCode]);
        if ([response statusCode] >=200 && [response statusCode] <300)
        {
            NSString *responseData = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:urlData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSLog(@"Response ==> %@", responseData);

            SBJsonParser *jsonParser = [SBJsonParser new];
            NSDictionary *jsonData = (NSDictionary *) [jsonParser objectWithString:responseData error:nil];
            NSLog(@"jsonData: %@",jsonData);
```

Here is php:

```
//retrieve the login details via POST
$username = $_POST ['username'];

$query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM inputs
WHERE user = '$username' AND ts = (SELECT MAX(`ts`)FROM inputs WHERE user =    '$username')");

//create a while loop that places the returned data into an array
while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

//store the returned data into a variable
$output = $list;

//encode the returned data in JSON format
echo json_encode($output);

}
//close connection
mysql_close();

?>
```

Comment: If under normal circumstances only one row is returned from the database, the PHP part of this code would work. But, if there are two or more rows in the inputs table where ts is equal for this user, the json data will be printed more than once because the echo is inside the while loop.

Comment: kimg - you are correct, the there were two identical time stamps thus causing json invalid.  thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build the output array, then output your json.  What might be happening is you are sending valid json the first time, and then as you continue to ech, it becomes invalid because you strings like:

```
{test: 1}{hello: 2}
```

isn't valid json.

```
$output = array();

//create a while loop that places the returned data into an array
while ($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){

//store the returned data into a variable
$output[] = $list;
}

//encode the returned data in JSON format
echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: Kirk - thanks for tips.  Time stamp was identical causing two json outputs, thus making it invalid.